# Connection details for Priority Web API sand box (demo environment)

Tags: priority-web-sdk

According to the Web API [introduction page](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/tutorial/#Introduction), I have to connect to the development environment by calling the [login(...)](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/global/#login) function passing it the following configuration object:

```
{
    username: '<username>', 
    password: '<password>', 
    url: '<url>', 
    tabulaini: '<tabula.ini>', 
    language: <language>,  
    company: '<companyName>', 
    appname: 'Customers'
}
```

Does the Prioritysoftware provides connection settings details (username, password, url, etc.) for Priority **Web API** demo environment as it provides for Priority **REST API** demo environment (using the following [postman collection](https://app.getpostman.com/run-collection/eb6e9f048cbc69097ccc))?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. Try

```js
var configuration = {
    username: 'apidemo',
    password: '123',
    url: 'https://www.eshbelsaas.com/ui',
    tabulaini: 'tabmob.ini',
    language: 3,
    company: 'usdemo'
};
```